# Calabi-Yau cohomology?

Tags: cohomology, stable-homotopy, string-theory

My question here is going to be this -- but I'll give a bit of background to explain myself in a moment:

*What has been done/what results are available on [Calabi-Yau cohomology](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Calabi-Yau+cohomology) in degree $n \geq 3$ (in particular $n =3$)?*

Here by *Calabi-Yau cohomology* I mean [complex oriented cohomology theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/complex%20oriented%20cohomology%20theory) with [formal group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/formal%20group) being (equivalent to) the [Artin-Mazur formal group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Artin-Mazur%20formal%20group) $\Phi^n_X$ of a given [Calabi-Yau variety](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Calabi-Yau%20variety) of dimension $n$. (So in particular this here is *not* about cohomology *of* Calabi-Yau varieties. I am aware that this will now make 90% of all readers frown, but I can't help it.)

To put this in perspective:

In discussion of [elliptic cohomology](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elliptic%20cohomology) it is traditional to think of the formal group associated with the [elliptic spectrum](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/elliptic%20spectrum) as "being" the formal completion of the given elliptic curve. But the [story](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivariant%20elliptic%20cohomology#InterpretationInQuantumFieldTheory) of [equivariant elliptic cohomology](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivariant%20elliptic%20cohomology) shows that more properly that formal group is identified with the [formal Picard group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/formal%20Picard%20group) of the elliptic curve, namely the perturbation/deformation theory of the moduli of line bundles over it. It just so happens that elliptic curves are self-dual abelian varieties so that both these perspectives are equivalent, but the latter is the fundamental one that generalizes.

In the next step, [K3-cohomology](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/K3-cohomology) is complex oriented cohomology theory with formal group being the [formal Brauer group](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/formal%20Brauer%20group) of a [K3 surface](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/K3%20surface). This has been discussed.

But there is an obvious continuation of this story to higher $n$, and I am looking for whatever results exist for $n \geq 3$. My understanding is that Michael Hopkins talked about this "Calabi-Yau cohomology" at the Midwest Topology Seminar in 1992, but I haven't seen anything except this pointer.

Notice that the case $n = 3$ is quite compelling from the point of view of physics: while equivariant elliptic cohomology ("CY1-cohomology") [is essentially](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/equivariant%20elliptic%20cohomology#InterpretationInQuantumFieldTheory) the theory of the [modular functor](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/modular+functor) of [3d Chern-Simons theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chern-Simons%20theory)/[2d Wess-Zumino-Witten theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Wess-Zumino-Witten+model), so the Artin-Mazur formal group $\Phi^3_X$ is just the formal approximation to the [intermediate Jacobian](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/intermediate%20Jacobian) which is the [phase space](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/phase%20space) of $U(1)$-[7d Chern-Simons theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/7d%20Chern-Simons%20theory). It should be quite interesting to ask for a (equivariant) CY3-cohomology theory here which similarly captures the [geometric quantization](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric%20quantization) of this and hence yields the modular functor for the [infamous 6d theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/6d%20%282,0%29-supersymmetric%20QFT)...

There seems to be fairly strong motivation on the physics side for looking at CY3-cohomology, also if one looks at it from the perspective of [F'-theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/F%27-theory), and as such hypothetical Calabi-Yau cohomology was highlighted at the end of [Sati 05](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Calabi-Yau+cohomology#Sati05).

But so the **question** is: what is actually already known about CY3-cohomology? For instance: what are sufficient conditions for the Artin-Mazur formal group $\Phi^3_{CY3}$ to be Landweber exact??

Comment: A naive question: I chased your link to the nforum page on Artin-Mazur fg.  Looking at it, I don't see what is special about Calabi-Yau varieties, over arbitrary ones of dim n.  I'm guessing  the CY condition is what's need to make the AMfg one dimensional, yes?

Comment: To guarantee that $\Phi^n$ be prorepresentable by a formal group, it suffices to have $\Phi^{n-1}$ be formally smooth. The condition that $H^{n-1}(X, \mathcal{O}_X)=0$ is an overly strong way to guarantee that. Then yes, $\dim H^n(X, \mathcal{O}_X)$ gives the dimension of the formal group $\Phi^n$, so for a Calabi-Yau it is one-dimensional.

Comment: @CharlesRezk, true, I should have mentioned this. For completeness I have now added a brief remark on that to the relevant nLab entry: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Artin-Mazur+formal+group#OfCalabiYauVarieties (just as Matt says, of course).

Comment: can I ask where the term "calabi-yau cohomology" was first coined?

Comment: ([Szymik 10](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/K3-spectrum#Szymik10)) ($\leftarrow$ mouseover) points in his reference item [19] to a "report" by Jack Morava on Mike Hopkins’ work on Calabi-Yau cohomology, which apparently, as I mentioned above, was presented in 1992 at the Midwest topology Seminar. But I haven't seen this report. The earliest mentioning that I have seen in print (so far) is ([Sati 05](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/K3-spectrum#Sati05)), where the terminology is proposed on the last page.

Comment: @UrsSchreiber Do you know about [this thesis](https://search.proquest.com/docview/814798658)? It seems relevant (though surprisingly hard to come across!).

Comment: @Emily thanks for the pointer. Have added it to the nLab here https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/K3-spectrum#Nogami10 with discussion here: https://nforum.ncatlab.org/discussion/5946/k3spectrum/?Focus=87972#Comment_87972